# Is doing this,is the right way with regard to performance and memory usage-leaks or is it a better way?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, button, memory-leaks, gdi

Ok i have a button lying on the top of a winform , in form constructor i have Graphics `obj = this.CreateGraphics();`

when mouse enter event is fired

```
MainFormGraphicsHandle.DrawRectangle( new Pen(Color.CornflowerBlue, 2.0f),
this.MdPlayerButton.Location.X - 2, this.MdPlayerButton.Location.Y - 2,
this.MdPlayerButton.Size.Width + 4, this.MdPlayerButton.Size.Height + 4);
```

when mouse leave is fired

> MainFormGraphicsHandle.DrawRectangle(new Pen(this.BackColor, 2.0f),
>   this.MdPlayerButton.Location.X - 2,this.MdPlayerButton.Location.Y - 2,
>   this.MdPlayerButton.Size.Width + 4, this.MdPlayerButton.Size.Height +
>   4);

Does drawing over rectangles over rectangles may lead to memory leak or something or is it a good practice to highlight buttons ?

i want to be able to resize my form,so using ready images and swaping between them is not prefferable .

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

WinForms uses GDI for graphics, and GDI is what's known as *immediate mode*. This means that you can draw one or a billion rectangles; this will only take as much memory as it takes to hold the resulting bitmap.

For improved efficiency you might want to manually dispose of the Pen you create, but if you don't, .NET will clean them up for you eventually anyway:

```
using (var pen = new Pen(...))
   DrawRectangle(pen, ...);
```